# background color for TooltipHost in fluent-ui

Tags: fluent-ui

Can I apply background color to the tooltip when using TooltipHost in fluent-ui?
I tried

```
const ttStyles: Partial<ITooltipHostStyles> = { 
    root: { display: 'inline-block', background:'yellow'} 
};
```

but it did not change the color.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TooltipHost is just a wrapper around an element, that should show a Tooltip, not the Tooltip itself. Hence, you need to set some styles on the Tooltip. But since the Tooltip is made up of a Callout component, you need to set the according styles on the underlying Callout component. Perhaps I missed something simpler, but this is what I needed to do in order to change the Tooltip's background color:

```
<TooltipHost
  content="Tooltip Content"
  tooltipProps={{
    calloutProps: {
      styles: {
        beak: { background: 'yellow' },
        beakCurtain: { background: 'yellow' },
        calloutMain: { background: 'yellow' },
      },
    },
  }}
>
  <Icon iconName="Info" />
</TooltipHost>
```

"beak" is the small triangle pointing at the Icon in this case. "beakCurtain" is the overall background of the visible callout. "calloutMain" then is the background behind the text in the Tooltip.

Comment: This great! Thank you much